# Disqus comments block no longer loading, was working before update

Tags: comments

After a recent update, loading Disqus through a block in my node template file no longer works. I know my Disqus settings are correct as it has been working for the past year with no issues. I recently upgraded to version 7.39, but am unsure from what version. The code that I use to load the Disqus block is:

```
$block = module_invoke('disqus', 'block_view', 'disqus_comments');
print render($block);
```

If I print the contents of the block array, it is empty.

```
print_r($block); => Array ( [subject] => [content] => )
```

Things I have tried:

- Disabling Disqus and enabling it.
- Changing location back to content area produced no results. Switched
  back to block and nothing.
- Turning on testing mode
- Using default options

Is anyone else having difficulties with Disqus not loading? My next step is to uninstall and reinstall Disqus but wanted to chech if anyone had any other suggestions before I do so. Thanks!